# convert epoch time to hours ago, min ago from current date in iphone

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter, epoch

I have epoch time is 1347522689. Now i want to show this time in how many hours ago , Minutes ago from the current date. I am new in this PLease show me some code or any advice be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: if you want to get year,month,day,hour,second then i have a nice code...

Comment: @Rajneesh071 yes pls show me your code.Very appreciated for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *epochTime = @"1347522689";
NSTimeInterval epochInterval = [epochTime longLongValue];
NSDate *epochNSDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:epochInterval];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterEpoch = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatterEpoch setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"];
NSString *epochDate = [dateFormatterEpoch stringFromDate:epochNSDate];

NSDate *currentDateNSDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterCurrent = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatterCurrent setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"];
NSString *currentDate = [dateFormatterCurrent stringFromDate:currentDateNSDate];


NSLog(@"epochDate = %@",epochDate);
NSLog(@"currentDate = %@", currentDate);

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSUInteger unitFlags = NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;

NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:epochNSDate toDate:currentDateNSDate options:0];

NSInteger year = [components month];
NSInteger months = [components month];
NSInteger days = [components day];
NSInteger hours = [components hour];
NSInteger min = [components minute];
NSInteger sec = [components second];


NSLog(@"Year Difference = %@\n Month Difference = %@\n, Days Difference = %@\n, Hours Difference = %@\n ,Minutes Difference = %@\n second Difference = %@\n", [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:year] stringValue] ,[[NSNumber numberWithInteger:months] stringValue], [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:days] stringValue], [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:hours] stringValue], [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:min] stringValue],[[NSNumber numberWithInteger:sec] stringValue]);
```

Comment: Hi Vakul, Thanks for your reply but i have tried it before still i am not getting like  2 hours ago, 2 Minutes ago from epoch time. I think we need to compare first last epoch time to current epoch time.

Comment: It will convert epoch time to normal time ... I will post the accurate answer .... plz wait

Comment: Your welcome .... I also had to do R&D for this  :) Well glad to help you, Give me up vote now ;)

Comment: Don't worry i will definitely...:)

Answer (score 0):

Using the below code Its working perfectly.

```
- (NSString *)epochTimeConvert:(NSString *)strSeconds
{
    NSTimeInterval interval = [strSeconds doubleValue];
    //interval -= 3600;
    NSDate *online = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy"];
    return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:online];
}
```

Call like this

```
[self epochTimeConvert: 1347522689];
```

Comment: Hi Mani, Thanks for your reply but i need to show to compare from current date then show time and minutes in ago. For Example i post something before two days then i want 2 days ago from epoch time. I hope you will help me.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the older question date, i put here this function to convert seconds in a format like

**2 days, 9 hours ago**

```
-(NSString*)humanReadableElapsedTimeForSeconds:(long)seconds WithUnitLabels:(NSArray*)customNames AgoLabel:(NSString*)customAgoLabel
{
    NSArray* names = ( customNames && [customNames count] == 7 ? customNames : @[@"seconds", @"minutes", @"hours", @"days", @"weeks", @"months", @"years"] );
    NSUInteger values[7] = {1, 60, 3600, 24 * 3600, 7 * 24 * 3600, 30 * 24 * 3600, 365 * 24 * 3600};
    NSString* agoLbl = (customAgoLabel ? customAgoLabel : @"ago");

    if (seconds < 0)
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0 %@",[names objectAtIndex:0]];

    NSString* hrElapsedTime = nil;

    int i = 0;
    for(i = (sizeof(values)/sizeof(values[0])) - 1; i > 0 && seconds < values[i]; i--);

    if(i == 0) {
        hrElapsedTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@ %@",(int)floorf(seconds / (float)values[i]),[names objectAtIndex:i], agoLbl];
    } else {
        unsigned long t1 = (unsigned long)floorf(seconds / (float)values[i]);
        unsigned long t2 = (unsigned long)floorf((seconds - t1 * values[i]) / (float)values[i-1]);
        if (t2 == 0)
            hrElapsedTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu %@ %@", t1, [names objectAtIndex:i], agoLbl];
        else
            hrElapsedTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu %@, %lu %@ %@", t1, [names objectAtIndex:i], t2, [names objectAtIndex:(i-1)], agoLbl];
    }

    return hrElapsedTime;
}
```

And so from a date:

```
-(NSString*)humanReadableElapsedTimeFromDate:(NSDate*)fromDate WithUnitLabels:(NSArray*)customNames AgoLabel:(NSString*)customAgoLabel
{
    if (!fromDate)
        return nil;

    NSTimeInterval seconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:fromDate];
    return [self humanReadableElapsedTimeForSeconds:seconds WithUnitLabels:customNames AgoLabel:customAgoLabel];
}
```

**Usage:**

```
//from seconds ( in this case will output '3 minutes, 20 seconds ago' )
[self humanReadableElapsedTimeForSeconds:200 WithUnitLabels:nil AgoLabel:nil];
// from date
[self humanReadableElapsedTimeFromDate:someDate WithUnitLabels:nil AgoLabel:nil];
```

Hope it could be helpful

Comment: @CyberMew Sorry, it's just nil check, like '(!fromDate ? YES : NO)', i'll update the answer, thanks